# how jpeg image upload issue in php

Tags: php, gd

Can anyone tell me, how to fix this following issues?

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: in /var/www/html/_controls/_images.php on line 28

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: '/var/tmp/phpaFbMJV' is not a valid JPEG file in /var/www/html/_controls/_images.php on line 28

Warning: imagecopyresampled(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in /var/www/html/_controls/_images.php on line 52

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: in /var/www/html/_controls/_images.php on line 28

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: '/var/tmp/phpaFbMJV' is not a valid JPEG file in /var/www/html/_controls/_images.php on line 28

Warning: imagecopyresampled(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in /var/www/html/_controls/_images.php on line 52

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: in /var/www/html/_controls/_images.php on line 28

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: '/var/tmp/phpUakeQQ' is not a valid JPEG file in /var/www/html/_controls/_images.php on line 28

Warning: imagecopyresampled(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in /var/www/html/_controls/_images.php on line 52

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/_controls/_images.php:28) in /var/www/html/_templates/code/admin/edit_project_image.php on line 40
```

**My source code:**

```
    <?
class image_control
{
     public $raw_image = "";
     public $temp_loc = "";

     public $image = "";
     public $image_resized = "";

     public $name = "";
     public $type = "";
     public $width = "";
     public $height = "";

     public $resize_to_width = "";
     public $resize_to_height = "";

     public $errors = array();

     function __construct($raw_file_post){
          $this->raw_image = $raw_file_post;

          $this->temp_loc = $raw_file_post['tmp_name'];
          $this->name = $raw_file_post['name'];

          if($raw_file_post['type'] == "image/jpeg" || $raw_file_post['type'] == "image/pjpeg"){
               $this->type = 'jpeg';
               $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->temp_loc);
          }
          elseif($raw_file_post['type'] == "image/png" || $raw_file_post['type'] == "image/x-png"){
               $this->type = 'png';
               $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($this->temp_loc);
          }
          elseif($raw_file_post['type'] == "image/gif"){
               $this->type = 'gif';
               $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($this->temp_loc);
          }
          else
               $error[] = 001;

          list($this->width, $this->height) = getimagesize($this->temp_loc);

          $this->image_resized = imagecreatetruecolor($this->width, $this->height);

          imageantialias($this->image_resized, true);

          imagealphablending($this->image_resized, false);
          imagesavealpha($this->image_resized,true);
          $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->image_resized, 255, 255, 255, 127);
          imagefilledrectangle($this->image_resized, 0, 0, $this->width, $this->height, $transparent);

          imagecopyresampled($this->image_resized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->width, $this->height, $this->width, $this->height);
          $this->image = $this->image_resized;
          $this->image_resized = "";
     }

     function resize($width, $height, $resample = false){
          if($width !== '' && $width !== NULL && $width !== 'auto')
               $this->resize_to_width = $width;

          if($height !== '' && $height !== NULL && $height !== 'auto')
               $this->resize_to_height = $height;

          if($width == 'auto' || $height == 'auto'){
               if($height == 'auto')
                    $this->resize_to_height = ($this->resize_to_width / $this->width) * $this->height;

               if($width == 'auto')
                    $this->resize_to_width = ($this->resize_to_height / $this->height) * $this->width;
          }

          $this->image_resized = imagecreatetruecolor($this->resize_to_width, $this->resize_to_height);

          imageantialias($this->image_resized, true);

          imagealphablending($this->image_resized, false);
          imagesavealpha($this->image_resized,true);
          $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->image_resized, 255, 255, 255, 127);
          imagefilledrectangle($this->image_resized, 0, 0, $this->resize_to_width, $this->resize_to_height, $transparent);

          imagecopyresampled($this->image_resized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->resize_to_width, $this->resize_to_height, $this->width, $this->height);

          if($resample == true){
              $this->image = $this->image_resized;
              $this->width = $this->resize_to_width;
              $this->height = $this->resize_to_height;

              $this->image_resized = "";
              $this->resize_to_width = "";
              $this->resize_to_height = "";
          }
     }

     function save($folder_dir, $name){
          if(is_dir($folder_dir)){
               if($this->type == 'jpeg')
                    imagejpeg($this->image, $folder_dir . '/' . $name . '.jpg', 100)
                         or die('Image error');
               elseif($this->type == 'png')
                    imagepng($this->image, $folder_dir . '/' . $name . '.png')
                         or die('Image error');
               elseif($this->type == 'gif')
                    imagegif($this->image, $folder_dir . '/' . $name . '.gif')
                         or die('Image error');
          }
          else
               return false;

          return true;
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: We can help you if you show your codes

Comment: Check if GD library is installed or not
http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

Comment: @Confused, GD is installed since the error would be different, something like `Warning: some function has been disabled..`

Answer (score 0):

```
/var/tmp/phpaFbMJV' is not a valid JPEG file
```

phpaFbMJV apparently is not a JPEG file?

Comment: Means i didn't get u, please can u tell me clearly. but i uploaded valid jpeg image file.

Comment: @ramkumar Try to simply move the image using `move_uploaded_file` and download it to see what the server receives.

Comment: You're missed some code from your question. What are the contents of the `$raw_file_post` array?

Answer (score 0):

The file that you are providing is not the valid please check the file. Only extension .jpg is not necessarily be a valid jpg formatted image.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the content-type header can easily be overwritten by some user trying to find exploits, I recommand you to open your file using [imagecreatefromstring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php).

```
$this->image = @imagecreatefromstring(@file_get_contents($this->temp_loc));
if ($this->image === false) {
  throw new Exception("File is unreachable or not a supported image");
}
```

Next, you want to keep your image format while saving them. I suggest you to use only one format, such as png, so all your images are now of the same type and you don't need to worry about that anymore.